# UIView.center = UIImageView.center but image view doesn't seem to be in centre in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview, alignment

I am making application for iPad, only landscape mode will be supported. I am having a `UIView` and later I am dynamically adding `UIImageView` as a subview. However my goal is to add images in centre of the `UIView`. So I used this code,

```
[imageView setCenter:dynamicMainView.center];
```

where imageView is `UIImageView`(Obvious :)) and dynamicMainView is `UIView`, However final outcome docent seem to be in centre,

**Visual Representation**

[image]

---

Full method code for adding UIImageView in UIView is,

```
-(void) addImageIntoMainDynamicView:(UIImage *) image
{
    [self clearImageFromMainDynamicView];//Always clear Dynamic main view before adding new views
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];  
        if(imageView.bounds.size.width > dynamicMainView.bounds.size.width || imageView.bounds.size.height > dynamicMainView.bounds.size.height)
        {
            [imageView setFrame:[dynamicMainView bounds]];
        }

        [imageView setCenter:dynamicMainView.center];
        NSLog(@"Image : X = %f and Y = %f", imageView.center.x,imageView.center.y );
        NSLog(@"UIView : X = %f and Y = %f", dynamicMainView.center.x,dynamicMainView.center.y );
        [dynamicMainView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

And above log value is,

```
2011-12-21 21:07:11.850 Map1TestApp[94645:11603] Image : X = 512.000000 and Y = 371.500000
2011-12-21 21:07:11.853 Map1TestApp[94645:11603] UIView : X = 512.000000 and Y = 371.500000
```

Any clue about why it's not adding in centre? Am I doing something wrong?

---

**FOR FUTURE VIEWER THE ANWSER WAS :**

```
[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([dynamicMainView bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([dynamicMainView bounds]))];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `center` of a view is expressed in it's superview's coordinate system. So you are centering your image view in the wrong coordinate system. (dynamic view's superview as opposed to dynamic view)

To centre view A within view B, the centre point of view A has to be the centre of the `bounds` rectangle of view B. You can get this using (from memory!) `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY`.

Comment: So hang check my understanding, Before I was getting a Frame bound which is whole screen rather than just a UIView space(Rect)? But now I am getting centre go UIView's CGRect? AM I right?

Comment: Yes, that's it. bounds is the size of the view in the views own coordinate system (origin 0,0). Frame is the size of the view but the origin is the point in the superview's coordinate system where the top left corner is. The center property is in the superview's coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the size of the image. Frame of the image may not be the frame of the UIImageView. Set the background color of the UIImageView to something like `[UIColor redColor]` and clipToBounds to true and see what'll happen. If there are red parts that are visible the problem is with the contentMode property of your imageView object.

Comment: Yeah I checked that before lol, it was fine, but jrturton's suggestion worked. I have posted a snippet which solved my prob :)